# how to mount a network drive from specified network adapter in freebsd

Tags: networking, unix, mount, routing, freebsd

I want to mount a network shared drive by my freebsd 9.3. I know This is possible by:

```
mount_smbfs -I 10.1.1.20 //user@10.1.1.20/shared /root/local_folder/
```

This is done by default from `em0`. How can I do this to perform this from other interface such as `em2`?

**EDIT:**
I have added a route to access the IP address of the shared drive from em2. I think this is not performing correctly. Can please help me about that?

```
static_routes="lan mumoffice foo"

route_foo="-host 10.1.1.20 -iface em2"
```

and then:

```
/etc/rc.d/netif restart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a routing question. `mount_smbfs` will let FreeBSD decide which IP and Interface to use. From your question I get that `em0` and `em2` are both in the same subnet as the target `10.1.1.20`? If this is the case you could change the interface metric of `em0` to be higher than `em2`. FreeBSD will then choose `em2` for outbound connections to this subnet. This is however not limited to `mount_smbfs` but all network communication. Perhaps more can be said on the topic if you specify why you want to make the data pass through the other interface?

Comment: Yes you'r right; both IP addresses are in same subnet. I am working with a security appliance that must send alerts from another port (em2). I added a static route for em2 to have access to the shared drive from em2. Please see my edits.

Comment: try ifconfig em0 metric 10 from the command line. The default interface metric is 0 so the system should from this point start to prefer em2 for outbound traffic. If this fixes your problem the next question is how exactly to put this in rc.conf. Probably simply by appending it to the ifconfig_em0 line...

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem; setting metric option influences routing in a general way; if I could find a way to specify output interface for specific host or IP range; it was better.

Comment: In linux versions such as ubuntu each network interface has it's own default route IP; but in freebsd there is just one default route IP for all network applications and metric has more essential role.

Comment: There are actually a few options you have to solve this in a less general way. You could install multiple routing tables and let mount_smbfs use a secondary route table. For this you need to recompile the kernel with this option on and investigate the setfib tool. Another option might be using ipfw in combination with the fwd rule. The ability to add multiple default routes is not the issue here sajad. For this network there are actually already 2 routes in place. with the interface metric we are telling FreeBSD which route it should prefer.